# What happens when per-user MSI is uninstalled?

Tags: deployment, windows-installer

If several users install the same per-user MSI on the one workstation, what happens if one of those users performs an uninstallation of the app when they are logged on?

Will Windows wait until all users have executed the uninstall before it completely uninstalls the app?

Comment: Remember that a per-user install is meant to install into a location ( in their profile ) that they can write to.  This means not Program Files.

Comment: But it will install the application files into Program Files won't it?

Comment: @CraigJ No, it won't. Per-user installation will not be installed to Program Files (at least by default). Per-user installation is run unelevated since no changes to the system-wide settings are made. Thus even non-administrators can install such packages.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov: This is not true for Vista and earlier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd765197(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: For Vista and earlier, per-user apps will be installed into the standard Program Files folder: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd765197(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: And what a horribly broken design that was.  Think about it.  If the user doesn't have admin (locked down) then the install fails.  If the user does have admin the files get installed into an all users location.  It's "installed" for everyone, i.e. taking up the disk space in a place other users can see it... they are just missing the final shortcuts and registry to make it work.

Comment: Personally I don't waste my breath on Per-User installs.  They are really only meant for viral applications in locked down environments.  Something ClickOnce is better at in the first place.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: aren't per-user installs designed for GPO environments so that registry/env-vars/appdata is all per-user and everything is sorted out properly?  How are you going to do this with per-machine?

Comment: GPO can distribute a Per-Machine MSI also.  But realize that very few people ever used GPO deployment.  It's very flaky and has limitations such as only being able to associate a single file ( MSI ) with no additional files such as cab's or transforms.  All the big boys use other tools such as Tivoli and SCCM.  GPO has almost no use in the real world.

Comment: Also realize that MSI supports a concept called Managed ( aka Elevated aka Advertised aka Published ) installs where a non-priv user can install a per-machine install.

Answer (score 3):

A package installed only for the current user will be uninstalled only for the current user. Other user accounts are not affected.

So the other users will still have the product installed.

Comment: What if an administrator account is logged in and the app is uninstalled?  Will all standard users lose it?

Comment: No. A per-user installation doesn't affect other user accounts, even if the current user is an Administrator.

Comment: So an Administrator cannot remove a per-user installation from the machine unless they log in as that user?

Comment: Yes. A per-user install can be accessed only by the user account on which it was performed. Read this article to better understand per-user and per-machine installs: http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-environment/peruser-permachine/

Comment: That link doesn't address my concern: can an Administrator completely remove a per-user app from a machine if they want to?

Comment: Here's a link that will.  The answer is "No". See Rule 30 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/05/24/605835.aspx